# Why am I getting an exception from PHP CodeSniffer?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

Well, I'm getting a pretty bizarre error from PHPCS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkstyle version="1.2.2">
 <file name="/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Goals/workspace/Goals/controllers/UserActivation.class.php">
  <error line="1" column="1" severity="error" message="An error occurred during processing; checking has been aborted. The error message was: $stackPtr is not a class member var" source="unknownSniff"/>
 </file>
</checkstyle>
```

Any hints on what's going on here? Something similar has been mentioned in bug reports on PEAR, but it looks like it was fixed in 2009. I'm running the latest version of PHPCS, so idk what to think.

Comment: Could you post the code in UserActivation.class.php?

Comment: Agreed php Errors are typically vague and could have several meanings. Mind posting the actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been solved. I'm not sure what the issue was except that my Ant build file was not working as it should. For those running Hudson CI (which I was during this issue), Sebastian Bergmann has a great template for doing Ant builds. Find it here: http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-hudson-template